# Obj-C: system("echo -e ...") and cron without mail

Tags: objective-c, system, cron

In a small backup utility, I'm trying to use system() to write to the user cron table in objective-c.

Now I'm doing this:

```
NSString *croncmd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"echo -e 'MAILTO=\"\" \n*/1 * * * * \"%@/Library/Application Support/LBKP/cron/croncall\" %@ > /dev/null 2>&1' | crontab" , NSHomeDirectory(), backup_id ];

system([croncmd UTF8String]);
```

As you can see, first I simply tried to use `> /dev/null 2>&1` to get rid of the mails in case of error... but in OSX seems like it doesn't work at all and I still get emails.

Then reading some info online I just come across the usage of `MAILTO=""` at the start of the cron table to discard all the outputs.

The problem is that I need to echo a "new line" to the crontab file witch can usually be made using the `-e` option and `\n` char in the terminal, but if I do it from my program I get this in the console:

`17/09/11 16:32:52,590 [0x0-0x3a03a].com.home.LBKP: "-":0: bad minute`

What's the problem? :S How can I get rid of this error or just the output?

Thanks!

Comment: First off, I'd suggest you take a look at the [`NSTask` Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html). `system()` is evil.

Comment: Hi, I'm using [Interacting with the Operating System](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OperatingSystem/OperatingSystem.html) from Apple in another App but in this one system() even if evil is fastest way to go... thanks for the feedback anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered that the problem was caused when I added quotes and other things to make the NSString... Anyway I found that the safest way to do this is:

```
NSString *disbl_mail = @"echo 'MAILTO=\"\"' | crontab"; // Disable all cron mail...
system([disbl_mail UTF8String]);

NSString *croncmd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(crontab -l; echo '*/1 * * * * \"%@/Library/Application Support/LBKP/cron/croncall\" %@ > /dev/null 2>&1') | crontab -" , NSHomeDirectory(), backup_id ];
system([croncmd UTF8String]);
```

The second command syntax `(crontab -l; echo` lists the available info on the cron table and then echoes it and the new command back to the cron. This way the previous `MAILTO=""` entry will not be deleted.

Anyway, and specially because I know this is not the best way to add stuff to the crontab I'm posting a new question here: [Obj-C: What is the best way to add jobs to crontab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462311/obj-c-what-is-the-best-way-to-add-jobs-to-crontab).

Hope this can me useful to someone!