# What is the best way to add jobs to crontab?

Tags: objective-c, cron

My question is simple, what's the best way to add (and remove...) a job to/from crontab in Objective-C?
Normally I would use this:

```
NSString *croncmd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(crontab -l; echo '*/1 * * * * \"%@/Library/Application Support/iKlive/chksec\" %@ > /dev/null 2>&1') | crontab -" , NSHomeDirectory(), backup_id ];
system([croncmd UTF8String]); // Or NSTask...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Since you're using OS X, you should probably be using [launchd](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/launchd.8.html). There's a [sample daemon](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SampleD/Introduction/Intro.html) project to get started.

Comment: I found this website that provides a really good tutorial about launchd:  http://www.devdaily.com/mac-os-x/mac-osx-startup-crontab-launchd-jobs. Thanks!